# How to describe a nil object in Swift in terms of existence and its value?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Can one say that a nil object in Swift exists?
So take for example an array that is declared as an optional type.

```
var books : [Book]?
```

This array starts out as a nil object, but does it still somehow exist by virtue of it being declared an optional which suggests it might have a value at some point?

Just in terms of properly describing and understanding a nil object, is this accurate: "a nil object does not yet exist and does not yet have a value, but later may be brought into existence by being given a value"?

Comment: A nil object is nil and has no value. A optional variable can contain a value, but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, an optional can *contain* `nil`, but `nil` itself represents the absence of a value. When you write something like you described:

```
var books : [Book]?
```

Space is allocated to potentially contain something there in the future, and it is initialized to be an `Optional<Array<Book>>`, but its value is assigned to be `nil`, which effectively does not exist. `nil` is only technically a value in thought, in that a variable can be assigned `nil`. In reality, it is the lack of a value

Answer (score 2):

Swift's optional type is implemented using an enumeration

```
enum OptionalValue<T> {
    case none
    case some(T)
}
```

So when nil is assigned to an optional value, I think it has that `none` case assigned to it. and appropriate memory allocated.

You can get further details here:- https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift

Answer (score 1):

The variable `books` exists, but it is not an object.  It has the value `OptionalValue.none`.

A value (or reference) can later be assigned to an optional variable but this does not “bring the variable into existence”; it always existed it just had nothing assigned to it.

The creation of an object, value or struct that is assigned to the variable is separate from the creation of the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

As Aks says in his answer, and optional is an enum with two possible values, `.some` and `.none`.

Quoting Aks's answer (and the Apple docs) :

```
enum OptionalValue<T> {
    case none
    case some(T)
}
```

The `.none` case does not contain an associated value.

The `.some` case contains an associated value.

Swift enums are defined using generics, so you can have an optional with a type, like Optional(Int).

When you create an optional, you're defining an enum. That enum exists. Think of it as a box. The box may be empty (the `.none` case) or it may contain something (the `.some` case) but the box exists when it's created.